# Any built-in serialazer JSONapi in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, serialization

In Rails 4 we use active_model_serializers gem to make JSONapi. May be Rails 5 has own  tools for serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't find such built-in tool. Just two major gems: `active_model_serializers` and `jbuilder`. In `active_model_serializers` you should write ruby classes for serializers, so there isn't specific syntax. But in `jbuilder` you should use `*.json.jbuilder` files for rendering json and there are "syntactic sugar" and builder-style DSL. JBuilder is my choice)